# Нужна ли запятая, если "как всегда" находится в конце предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

Знаю, что по правилам "слова «как всегда» не являются вводными и не обособляются, если они входят в состав сказуемого или тесно связаны с ним по смыслу".

Но вот, к примеру, в предложении **"Она хороша(,) как всегда"** так и тянет опустить запятую. Слово "хороша", как я поняла, едва ли является сказуемым, однако почему-то есть интуитивное ощущение той самой тесной смысловой связи, и потому - неотчуждаемости. Является ли данное ощущение верным? Может ли пунктуация в подобных случаях быть вариативной или нет? Как бы вы поступили - оставили бы запятую или опустили ее?

Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Она хороша, как всегда.

(Хороша - именная часть сказуемого, выраженная кратким прилагательным).

Здесь "как всегда" - это вводное словосочетание, которое обособляется или отделяется запятой в конце предложения.

Сравнить: Здесь всё **было как всегда**. Оборот входит в состав сказуемого и не обособляется.

Comment: А почему вводное? Это сравнительный оборот. Характер вводных слов имеют сравнительные обороты как нарочно, как правило - здесь есть отношение к тому, о чём говорится: Как нарочно, в кармане не было ни копейки (сожаление).Запятыми, как правило, выделяются деепричастные обороты (степень обычности сообщаемого: не абсолютно всегда, а как правило, обычно). А как всегда - сравнение, можно И подставить: как и всегда.

Comment: В справочнике "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации" этот оборот назван вводным, также как и оборот "как обычно". Думаю, что эти обороты относятся к тематике вводных слов, а именно оценка говорящим степени обычности события.

Comment: Разве признаком сравнения не является возможность заменить "как" на "подобно"? В данном случае эта замена невозможна.

Comment: Розенталь в "Справочнике по правописанию и литерат. правке" в параграфе "Сравнит оборот"  говорит более осторожно:4) обособляется, если если оборот выражается сочетанием как правило, как исключение, как обычно, как всегда, как прежде, как сейчас, как теперь, как нарочно и т.п. (некоторые из них имеют характер вводных слов), например: Вижу, как теперь, самого хозяина... (Пушкин); Занятия начались, как обычно, в девять часов утра; Помню, как сейчас, свою первую учительницу в школе; Запятыми, как правило, выделяются деепричастные обороты.

Comment: возможность заменить "как" на "подобно" - не единственный признак сравнительных оборотов, главный всё-таки семантика, а здесь она есть:Она хороша так, как хороша всегда. Оттенок вводности здесь есть, конечно. Я просто против термина "вводное сочетание". Это сравнительный оборот с оттенком вводности. А вводное  со знач. степени обычности - обыкновенно, по обыкновению.